# Xamarin IOS in Visual Studio Preview 19 says IOS Designer going away, but no links on how to use Xcode

Tags: .net, windows, xamarin.ios

Does this mean I have to code on my mac now for ios if my visual studio updates.  I had a side by side installation so I am using my Visual Studio 2019 preview for now.

Is there a way to design ios apps on Xamarin for the preview Visual Studio? IS this being worked on later?  The screen says ios designer is going away and even though everything updated, the storyboard never loaded.

Regards,

Nathaniel

Comment: This seems a new issue/feature! in the production version of Visual Studio for Windows v16.8.0. Anybody has a solution?

Comment: Seems like they decided that people don't need their designer. Have the same problem with visual studio Mac. I've also seen the message but it loaded after a while.

Comment: In Visual Studio for Mac, Xcode is used as a designer, but it is not the case for Windows at the moment.